# Reorder a muti-dimensional array based on a hash map in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d-array `questionOrder` of variable number of rows and columns. The array is stored as JSON in the database. I have a requirment to change the order of the elements based on the keys of input linked map `questions` (values are not relevant for the ordering.

Example:

```
questionOrder = [[2, 3, 4], [5, 7], [8]]
questions     = {2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 7}  // values omitted
desired output: [[2, 3], [5, 4, 8, 7]]
```

That means:

- 4 & 8 change their position from 1st and 3rd sub array to 2nd sub array
- sub array 3rd is removed from `questionOrder` because it is emtpy.

My code so far is

```
Map<Long, Long> questions = form.getQuestions();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
long[][] questionOrder = gson.fromJson(myTemplate.getQuestionOrder(), 
                                       long[][].class);
```

SO I am thinking to make an array `questionOrderBkp` to keep the `questionOrder` as temporary variable and find the first element in the  `questions` being diffrent from `questionsOrder` (4 in the example). Then find the position of 4 in `questions` and to that position insert all other elements(8 in the example). How can I do this easily with less time complexity?

Comment: Is there a mistake in your example `questions`? Shouldn't 4, 5, 7, and 8 be mapped to 2 instead of 1? And is it important that the second array is ordered 5-4-8-7; and if so, where is that order defined? Furthermore, are all numbers in `questionOrder` also present in `questions`; and if so, why do we need `questionOrder` at all; and if not, what happens to numbers that are not in `questions`?

Comment: @MalteHartwig It is not like that values in the `questions` have any relation with the position that are simply some other value that can be any value.We need to order the  `questionOrder` array based on the key value of `questions`

Comment: So `questions` is ordered, for example a LinkedHashMap?

Comment: @MalteHartwig consider `questions` as as a list of `[2,3,5,4,8,7]` then how we can do this?

Comment: @MalteHartwig yes questions is ordered. It is a LinkedHashMap

Comment: I still don't understand the rules how to split the ordered numbers up in sub lists. Why is 8 in the second array? Why not in a third array together with 7? Are all numbers automatically put in the second array as soon as you have a mismatch?

Comment: @MalteHartwig That logic is we are moving the all the items which is diffrent in position is moving to  second inner array as the first item(4) is placed in second inner array. for example if the questions array is `{2, 3, 5, 4,7,8}`  then the resultant array is `[[2, 3], [5, 4, 7],[8]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165054/discussion-between-senchu-thomas-and-malte-hartwig).